# Grouping people into sets to make sure every club is represented twice

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

There are some people in a school, each of whom is part of at least one club. Each club contains at least 2 people. For every pair of clubs, there exists at least one person in both clubs. Is there always a way to split the people into 3 groups such that each club shares members with at least 2 groups?

I think the answer is yes, although not much progress on proving this claim. I tried starting with a singular person, then considering the other people in this person's possibly singular club. But it is hard to see what will happen next.

I have also considered applying Hall's marriage lemma, but this has given no significant results

Comment: Didn't you post this question twice? or are you in the same class as the other person who posted this question? I refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4831325/how-to-group-students

Comment: Here's the comment I wrote on the other version of this question, which version has since been deleted. Divide the students any way you want into three disjoint (and nonempty) groups, call them groups A, B, and C. Let Club 1 contain groups A and B, Club 2 contain groups A and C, Club 3 contain groups B and C. This satisfies the conditions. I don't know what you mean by a "good" way to divide the students into groups – any way at all will work (so long as the groups are nonempty and disjoint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. Choose a club $X$ which is minimal, i.e., no proper subset of $X$ is a club. Choose a member $x$ of the club $X$. Put $x$ in the red group; put the remaining members of $X$ in the blue group; and put everybody else in the green group.  Any club that $x$ belongs to will have members in at least two different groups, since the club has at least two members and only one is in the red group. A club which does not have $x$ as a member must have at least one blue member (since it overlaps with club $X$) and at least one green member (as otherwise it would be a proper subset of club $X$).

Restating your exercise in standard mathematical jargon:

Let $H$ be a hypergraph. If the edges of $H$ are **finite** sets of size at least $2$, and if every pair of edges has nonempty intersection, then $H$ is $3$-colorable, *i.e.*, has chromatic number $\chi(H)\le3$.

In your story problem I guess it's tacitly assumed that a club has a finite number of members. You can't just drop the finiteness assumption; if the set of edges is a nonprincipal ultrafilter then the chromatic number will be at least $\aleph_0$. However, instead of assuming that all edges are finite, you could just assume that there is a minimal edge.

By the way, if $H=(V,\mathcal E)$ is a hypergraph with vertex set $V$ and edge set $\mathcal E$, such that every pair of edges has nonempty intersection and $H$ is not $3$-colorable, then $\mathcal U=\{U\subseteq V:\exists X\in\mathcal E,\  X\subseteq U\}$ is an ultrafilter on $V$.